# MyBatis nested parameter from HashMap

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

In mapper interface I have:

`ArrayList<Item> select(@Param("myFilter")int Filter myFilter);`

In class Filter I have:
`class Filter{ String str; HashMap<String,String> myMap; }`

My Map has:
`myMap.put("key1", "val1"); myMap.put("key2", "val2");`

In mapper xml I want to check muMap value in  and add in SQL code filter with this value, like:

`<select id="select" resultMap="RM"> SELECT ...  FROM .... WHERE id=#{myFilter.str} <if test="myFilter != null and myFilter.myMap !=null and myFilter.myMap.get('key1') != null> AND code = #{myFilter.myMap.get('key1')}; </if> </select>`

No errors but the result is not as expected (it returns empty set but I know item with such id exists).
The #{myFilter.myMap.get('key1')} and myFilter.myMap.get('key1') in  seems do not to work.
Where is my mistake? Thank you.

The #{myFilter.myMap.get('key1')} and myFilter.myMap.get('key1') in  seems do not to work.
Where is my mistake? Thank you.

Comment: Difficult to tell without debug info. Please enable DEBUG level for the mapper and add the log to the question. The debug level will show the input parameters and the actual/final SQL statement that is run.

Comment: @Dmytro There aren't enough information and the snippet you posted does not seem accurate, but (unlike `test` attribute of `<if>`) `#{}` does not support OGNL expression. To access map content, you need to use `#{myFilter.myMap.key1}` (OGNL supports this expression as well, BTW).